# How to capture output from continuous process in Python?

Tags: python

I am new to Python and Linux. I have a process running in a terminal window that will go indefinitely. The only way to stop it would be for it to crash or for me to hit ctrl+C. This process outputs text to the terminal window that I wish to capture with Python, so I can do some additional processing of that text.

I know I need to do something with getting stdout, but no matter what I try, I can't seem to capture the stdout correctly. Here is what I have so far.

```
import subprocess

command = 'echo this is a test. Does it come out as a single line?'

def myrun(cmd):
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

    stdout = []
    while True:
        line = p.stdout.read()
        stdout.append(line)

        if line == '' and p.poll() != None:
                break
    return ''.join(stdout)

result = myrun(command)
print('> ' + result),
```

This will work when my command is a simple "echo blah blah blah". I am guessing this is because the echo process terminates. If I try running the continuous command, the output is never captured. Is this possible to do?

Comment: do you mean to use `readline` and not `read`?

Comment: Perhaps you are struggling with the fact Python buffers it's output, try running your script with `python -u script.py` and see if it works

Answer (score 2):

`read()` will block on reading until reach EOF, use `read(1024)` or `readline()` instead:

> read(size=-1)
>
> Read and return up to size bytes. If the argument is omitted, None, or negative, data is read and returned until EOF is reached.

eg:

```
p = subprocess.Popen('yes', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

while True:
    line = p.stdout.readline()
    print(line.strip())
```

see more on the [python io doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase.read).